# Array filter only remove the values without whitespaces

Tags: php

Array Example

[image]

As the above pic show, the array_filter only remove the value which like ' ' without white space.
For the bottom that 2 value is empty also but because it have white spaces so it wont filter it.
Any solution? i try to preg_replace() and trim() also not able to remove the empty values with spaces...

Comment: Please include your array as __actual text__ - not an image!

Comment: Show the code for your array_filter, with the callback that you are using; and learn how to copy/paste code/text, not display images of it

Comment: use str_replace() method to replace your whitespace with null. Loop through the array and check if the value is white space..replace with ("") null and then use filter

Comment: function GetAPI($data, $value)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $product) {
        if (in_array("$value",$product)) {
            $filter= array_filter($result);
            $last = array_slice($filter, -1, true);
            $headers = array_slice($filter, 0, 2, true);
            $final =array_merge($headers, $last);
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: `array_filter($result);`.... so where is `$result` coming from? Do you mean `$product` instead of `$result`?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfa63f8cdfd95a10daff297c8f7d8148123d3c0b
Here is my code... for 2d arrays it just trim a part of white space, if 1d array it can trim all white space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `array_filter`, if no `callback` is supplied, all entries of array equal to `FALSE` will be removed. You can use the `callback` argument for `array_filter` to do this.

```
<?php

$array = [
    'varA' => '',
    'varB' => ' ',
    'varC' => '1',
    'varD' => '   ',
];

$newArr = array_filter($array, function($v, $k){
    return !empty(trim($v));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

var_dump($newArr);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Edit:

For a multi-dimensional array, you can traverse the array, and do the array_filter for each element. Performing the `str_replace` to each element is not a good practice: this slows down your code, and makes your code much more complex.

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'varA' => '',
        'varB' => ' ',
        'varC' => '1',
        'varD' => '   ',
    ),
    array(
        'varA' => '!!!',
        'varB' => '   ',
        'varC' => 'xxx',
        'varD' => '',
    )
);

$newArr = $array;
foreach ($newArr as &$each){
    $each = array_filter($each, function($v, $k){
        return !empty(trim($v));
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: the result is same, no changing :(

Comment: @hanjeahwan You sure running the same code as provided? My result printed has only varC left.

Comment: @hanjeahwan http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a7fee0dfd97d28e73281beec22a07df336b3925

Comment: i show u my code at the sandbox, if have 2 arrays within a array it will not remove all whitespaces, can u have a look?

Comment: @hanjeahwan you need to click share the code and paste the link here.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfa63f8cdfd95a10daff297c8f7d8148123d3c0b
Here is my code... for 2d arrays it just trim a part of white space, if 1d array it can trim all white space...

Comment: @hanjeahwan Performing the str_replace to each element is not a good practice: this slows down your code, and makes your code much more complex. You can think otherwise. `array_filter` a 2d array can be made via `traverse the 2d array` and `filter the value`, see my update in the answer.

Comment: @hanjeahwan also, I modified your code, and made it work. See: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7028012fdc9260a46ad9845de7f52c454fbc36c1

Comment: i dont know why i put in my code it not work,arhhh TT

Comment: @hanjeahwan `str_replace` is not efficient enough anyway for this case.

Comment: after i put in my code, it wont remove the last 2 values with white spaces. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/619490de82df7b143fc8f188dd1e84f885efbc92
here is the array result that i get.

Comment: @hanjeahwan I viewed the description of str_replace. It does not support your usage: replacing in the 2d array.

Comment: @hanjeahwan you mean you are using my code in your local environment? what is your php version then? cuz I noticed that php <5.6 does not have this feature yet.

Comment: @hanjeahwan I think your question is probably a problem around the `space`, and I just saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949441/php-fails-to-remove-white-spaces-from-a-arrays), maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to trim all values in the array and only retain the elements which contain at least one non-whitespace character, `preg_filter()` can do this in one step.

The pattern implements a non-greedy capture group to isolate a substring where the leading and/or trailing whitespaces are removed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/im1pG))

```
$array = [
    'one' => ' 1 ',
    'two' => '2',
    'three' => '',
    'four' => ' ',
    'five' => '0',
];

var_export(
    preg_filter('/^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$/', '$1', $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one' => '1',
  'two' => '2',
  'five' => '0',
)
```

A word of caution: if you use `array_filter()` without a custom callback function, then it will destroy zero-ish/falsey/null values.